# Run Safari from command line with URL parameter

Tags: macos, terminal, safari

I'm trying to open Safari (on OS X 10.8) from the terminal by executing the following:

```
open -a /Applications/Safari --args "http://www.example.com"
```

Safari opens and tries to navigate to the url:

```
file:///http:/www.example.com
```

Is there a way to get Safari to open up the browser at the specified url?

Note: I can't do `open http://www.example.com` because I can't be guaranteed that the Safari is the default browser. (And before I'm asked why I'm not using the default browser - I'm doing browser specific test automation.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would seem the answer is:

```
open -a safari http://www.example.com
```

According to the [man page for open(1)](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/open/),  *open -a <applicationName file>* opens a given file with a given application. Therefore, this seems like the most appropriate syntax.

[This forum thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2726849?start=0&tstart=0) explain more.

Comment: The correct syntax would be `open -a Safari --args example.com`, however Safari doesn't seem to have any documented example for opening a URL per https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8044532?answerId=32117821022#32117821022